# Should you call 'deleteLater' for objects that have not been assigned to variables?

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I have a program where I handle certain processes in a secondary thread, and I designed a decorator that does all the thread logic and can be wrapped around the method that produces the worker.

There is also some logic that involves animating the cursor and opening up a popup window that shows the progress and comes with a button to cancel the process. I found that for this to work, I have to assign both the cursor as well as the popup to attributes of the class whose method was called. Otherwise, the objects will disappear once the decorator logic is finished.

This is neither necessary for the worker nor for the secondary thread it is running in. I'm not sure I understand why though. In any case, once the process is finished, I call `deleteLater()` for the cursor and the popup, but not for the thread, since I believe it will be deleted anyways by the time the program moves on. Is that true? Or would it be good practice to call `deleteLater()` on the thread in any case? Should I even assign the thread (and worker) to an attribute of the class as well?

Here is some sample code:

**EDIT:** provided an MWE although only the logic of the decorator is important, the rest is just there to make it work.

```
import sys
import time
from functools import wraps
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QDialog, QPushButton, QProgressBar, QVBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit,
    QApplication
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor, QMovie, QTextCursor


def thread_out(title: str = 'Progress'):
    @wraps(title)
    def decorator(create_process):
        @wraps(create_process)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
            def stop_process() -> None:
                process.stop()
                process_thread.quit()
                process_thread.wait()
                self._wait_cursor.stop()
                self._wait_cursor.deleteLater()
                self._wait_cursor = None
                self._popup.close()
                self._popup.deleteLater()
                self._popup = None
                # should I also do process_thread.deleteLater()?

            def finish_process(data) -> None:
                finish(data)
                stop_process()

            self._popup = Popup()
            self._popup.canceled.connect(stop_process)
            self._wait_cursor = WaitCursor(
                [self, self._popup], QMovie('./movie.gif')
            )
            process_thread = QThread()
            process, finish = create_process(self, *args, *kwargs)
            process.moveToThread(process_thread)
            process.statusChanged.connect(self._report_status)
            process.progressed.connect(self._popup.update_progress)
            process.errorOccurred.connect(self._show_error_message)
            process.finished.connect(finish_process)
            process_thread.started.connect(self._wait_cursor.start)
            process_thread.started.connect(self._popup.show)
            process_thread.started.connect(process.run)
            process_thread.start()

        return wrapper

    return decorator


######### everything that follows is just there to make the MWE work


class Process(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(object)
    progressed = pyqtSignal(float)
    statusChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    errorOccurred = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._success = False
        self._isRunning = False
        self._stopped_messages = ['-- Canceled.\n', '-- Success.\n']

    def run(self):
        self._isRunning = True
        self.statusChanged.emit('-- Started.\n')
        i = 0
        while self._isRunning and i < 10:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            i += 1
            self.progressed.emit(i*10)

        if self._isRunning:
            self._success = True
            self._isRunning = False
            self.finished.emit(True)

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False
        message = self._stopped_messages[self._success]
        self.statusChanged.emit(message)


class Popup(QDialog):
    canceled = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, text_format: str = '%p%') -> None:
        super().__init__(flags=Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setFormat(text_format)
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton('Cancel')
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.cancel)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        lay.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def cancel(self) -> None:
        self.canceled.emit()

    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def update_progress(self, value) -> None:
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)


class WaitCursor(QObject):
    def __init__(self, widgets: list, movie: QMovie) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._movie = movie
        self._widgets = widgets
        self._last_cursors = {}
        self._movie.frameChanged.connect(self._on_frameChanged)

    def start(self) -> None:
        self._last_cursors.update(
            {widget: widget.cursor() for widget in self._widgets}
        )
        self._movie.start()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self._movie.stop()
        for widget, cursor in self._last_cursors.items():
            widget.setCursor(cursor)
        self._last_cursors.clear()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _on_frameChanged(self) -> None:
        cursor = QCursor(self._movie.currentPixmap())
        for widget in self._widgets:
            widget.setCursor(cursor)


class Program(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = None
        self._popup = None
        self._wait_cursor = None
        self.startProcessButton = QPushButton('Start Process')
        self.startProcessButton.clicked.connect(self._start_process)
        self.programStatus = QPlainTextEdit()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.startProcessButton)
        lay.addWidget(self.programStatus)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    @thread_out()
    def _start_process(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Process(), self._process_finished

    def _process_finished(self, data):
        self._data = data

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def _report_status(self, text):
        self.programStatus.setPlainText(text)
        self.programStatus.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def _show_error_message(self, message: str):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Program()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does `create_process` do? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, `create_process` is the method the decorator wraps around and which returns the process worker. I consciously decided against an MWE here because I think the rest of the code wouldn't really add anything to it and just be distracting.

Comment: @musicamante I provided am MWE; though again, most of the code is irrelevant.